# Boolean expressions with strings and numbers

Tags: krl

I have two variables in my `pre` block, and I need a third (a boolean) that identifies whether certain properties hold of those two:

```
str = "some string from a datasource";
qty = 15; //Also from a datasource
```

The third variable, `valid`, needs to be true when `str` is not empty and `qty` is greater than 0. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh! I just figured it out:

```
valid = not (str eq "") && (qty > 0);
```

I had some syntax errors in the rest of my ruleset; that's where the trouble was coming from.